# build a release version

Tags: android, flutter, release

I want build a release version to publish on app store but he want my api to 31 at least and after i made that i find the below error
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined

Although i added the android:exported to the manifist also same problem[image]

added it to the mainfaist

Comment: whats is the question?

Answer (score 0):

You might have to customize this in an AndroidManifest that comes from a library or similar. To see a unified AndroidManifest you have to click on **Merged Manifest** in the bottom bar. Then you will most likely see other fields where you still need to set your **exported** flag.

[image]

To do this, just right click on the Acitivity, etc. and then click **Go to Declaration** to jump into the file.

Comment: i cant find the merged manifest to make the declaration any help ?

Comment: it's a flutter app

Comment: You can open the project with Android Studio to view the AndroidManifest. At the bottom you see 2 Tabs Text & Merged Manifest